# Exception deploy spring 5 application over Websphere 8.5.5.x

Tags: java, spring, migration, websphere

After migrating the application to Spring 5 and deploying to Websphere 8.5.5 we find this exception

```
com.mapfre.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.config.GaiaFrontEndViewResolverConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$376d466c.viewResolver(<generated>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:90)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 120 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;)Ljava/lang/Object;" during creation of class "org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$495/000000001CD61330": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@22830839" of class "org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$495/000000001CD61330" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@41cc1fbb" of class "org/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor" have different types for the method signature
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass(Native Method)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.spinInnerClass(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:339)
    at java.lang.invoke.InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.buildCallSite(InnerClassLambdaMetafactory.java:206)
    at java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:315)
    at java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle.resolveInvokeDynamic(MethodHandle.java:841)
    ... 135 common frames omitted
[1/4/19 8:45:44:743 UTC] 000000a7 webapp        E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp notifyServletContextCreated SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: {0}
                                 org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in com.mapfre.dgtp.gaiafrontend.core.config.GaiaFrontEndViewResolverConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver]: Factory method 'viewResolver' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: java.lang.LinkageError: loading constraint violation when overriding method "org/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor.intercept(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;[Ljava/lang/Object;Lorg/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodProxy;)Ljava/lang/Object;" during creation of class "org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$495/000000001CD61330": loader "java/lang/InternalAnonymousClassLoader@22830839" of class "org/springframework/context/annotation/ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor$$Lambda$495/000000001CD61330" and loader "com/ibm/ws/classloader/CompoundClassLoader@41cc1fbb" of class "org/springframework/cglib/proxy/MethodInterceptor" have different types for the method signature
    at
```

We have been able to see what happens in any bean factory that we have defined when the getObject () method is called

```
@Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver viewResolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setOrder(-1);
        viewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager().getObject());
        viewResolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews());
        viewResolver.setViewResolvers(viewResolvers());
        return viewResolver;
    }
```

the exception occurs when this line is executed

```
viewResolver.setContentNegotiationManager(contentNegotiationManager().getObject());
```

The same application with 4.3.x spring version does not happen.

Versión IBM Websphere

```
Installed Product
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Name                  IBM WebSphere Application Server
Version               8.5.5.13
ID                    BASE
Build Level           cf131801.05
Build Date            1/12/18
Package               com.ibm.websphere.DEVELOPERSILAN.v85_8.5.5013.20180112_1418
Java SE Version       8
Architecture          x86-64 (64 bit)
Installed Features    IBM 64-bit WebSphere SDK for Java
                      WebSphere Application Server Full Profile
                      EJBDeploy tool for pre-EJB 3.0 modules
                      Embeddable EJB container
                      Stand-alone thin clients and resource adapters

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
End Installation Status Report
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Which fix level of WAS 8.5.5 and Java 8? I seem to recall some lambda fixes somewhere in a Java 8 fixpack, and maybe Spring 5 is using lambdas where 4.3 did not.

Comment: I believe Spring 5 relies on Java EE 7 support, which was not added in WebSphere until version 9.0.

Comment: A docker container version 8.5.5.13 is being tested. We already know that Spring 5 requires at least JEE 7+ as Websphere 9. However, JEE 7 technologies are not being used. We have deployed other applications that do not use this type of factory beans